# Making Apache PDFBox work with a Spring-AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, spring, pdfbox

I am working on a web application which have Spring for the backend and AngularJS for the front end. I need to include Apache PDFBox to my application for PDF reporting. I could make it work perfectly from the Spring part by using a RequestMapping and below are the codes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "app/rest/pdf/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getPdf(@PathVariable Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // the method call below creates the PDF using PDFBox.. details not shown
        output = printPdf(id);
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"test.pdf\"");
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        output.writeTo(os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, when I go to the RequestMapping link http://localhost:8080/myProject/app/rest/pdf/1234 (1234 being the id), the PDF opens up for me. All good. Now I need to get the PDF from the front end AngularJS app, where the PDF should be generated on a clicking a button. I can send the control to the backend by using an AngularJS service, and it enters the above method, but I am not sure how I should set it up in the AngularJS controller so that I can get the PDF. My efforts are below:

Page:

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="printPdf()">Print PDF Via PDBox</button>
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
 myApp.controller('PdfController', function ($scope, Pdf) {

     $scope.printPdf = function(){
        // Pdf is the service and this action calls the above backend method
        Pdf.get({id: $scope.report.id});
        // Not sure what to do here so that I can open the PDF
    }
```

Any help/suggestion appreciated.